# Thread also be run after killing the app is it possible in IOS

Tags: ios

Is it possible after killing the app any thread will run in background .IN ios is it possible to make a thread like it will will run during when app is running or also run a same thread after kill the app.Please suggest if it is possible in IOS

Answer (score 0):

When a process is terminated all its threads will be gone with it. You can only run code **before** process termination.

Answer (score 0):

No it is not possible. There are some special exceptions e.g. you can get location changes after quitting your app or you can have some "extra time" (I guess its 10minutes) to finish some savings.

Claus